# CSS: How do you remove style from child component (Tailwind)?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

[See code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3cEL.png)

I am importing a `<button>` component that has two `span` children. These span children are setting a gradient color that I want to override, but I only have access to the parent `<button>`. Is there a way for me to remove the styling on the children? I am using Tailwind.

Code:

```
<button className='from-orange-500 to-fuchsia-600'> // I want my button to be this gradient
   <span className='from-violet-400 dark:from-violet-400 to-violet-600 dark:to-violet-600'></span> // I want to delete these styles
   <span className='from-violet-600 dark:from-violet-600 to-violet-400 dark:to-violet-400'></span> // And these styles
</button>
```

And the component is being called as follows, which is why I can't target the spans:

```
<SubmitButton className="bg-gradient-to-l from-orange-500 to-fuchsia-600/>
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the classes from the children?

Comment: @Laisender Because I can only access the component as follows:

              <SubmitButton
                className="from-orange-500 to-fuchsia-600"
              />

Comment: Look for a file called SubmitButton.js or something like that. I didn't use React or Next so I can't really say where it will be but its probably somewhere in a class that extends `React.Component`

Comment: Do you own the `SubmitButton` component, or is from a component library? If you have control over it, can you share its code?